# When is the supersynchronous orbit more efficient than a typical Hohmann transfer where inclination change and circularization are simultaneous?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v, geostationary, hohmann-transfer, supersynchronous

The title essentially explains it all. Some GEO launch vehicles like Proton, which launches from Baikonur at a latitude of 46 degrees, launch into a supersynchronous orbit. So at what point is the supersynchronous, bi-elliptic transfer more efficient than the Hohmann transfer when launching into geostationary orbit?

Comment: See also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57669/6944

Comment: I would add one comment to the Op's question; normally the $\Delta_v$ in the previous answers on this forum usually give the $\Delta_v$ from LEO to GEO  via either GTO or via super synchronous.  But the $\Delta_v$ that matters is the $\Delta_v$ from GTO to GEO as compared with the $\Delta_v$ super synchronous orbit to GEO.  That's because the launch vehicle may have that extra capability built in for the extra $\Delta_v$ to get all the way to super synchronous orbit instead of GTO.  And if so, that saves on the additional $\Delta_v$ rockets in the payload required.

Comment: Also, the 2nd stage of the launch vehicle wants to stay in the GTO orbit (not GEO), so it can burn up as the perigee slowly degrades instead of becoming permanent GEO space junk.  So the launch vehicle can't go all the way to GEO, but the launch vehicle can go all the way to either GTO or super synchronous without creating space junk.  And I'm guessing it *always* requires less additional $\Delta_v$ from the payload's rockets if the launch vehicle goes *higher to super synchronous* instead of just GTO.

Comment: The _effective_ latitude of Baikonur for space-launch purposes isn't 46°; it's over 54°, because they can't launch directly east (they have to go northeast to keep from dropping rocket stages on China, never mind that China does that to itself all the time).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(mostly recycled from [What are the benefits of supersynchronous transfer orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57669/40257))

Excuse the wall of plots but I really do think they describe it better than my words ever could :)

---

The total $\Delta V$ costs for the standard (Hohmann like) method (inclined 250 km parking orbit to geostationary orbit) are:

[image: standard method]

While the total $\Delta V$ costs for the *supersynchronous* method are:

[image: super method]

The $\Delta V$ is lower for the supersynchronous method in the coloured regions of this plot:

[image: super better than standard]

The $\Delta V$ savings for the supersynchronous method is shown here (less than zero is less efficient):

[image: total savings]

---

However, when you **only consider the maneuvers that the spacecraft is (typically) responsible for** (i.e., post injection), it is ***always equal OR more efficient*** to use a supersynchronous transfer. The $\Delta V$ cost of the final burn for the standard method is:

[image: standard final burn]

For the supersynchronous method, the $\Delta V$ cost of the final two burns is:

[image: super final 2 burns]

The $\Delta V$ (final burn(s)) savings for the supersynchronous method are shown here:

[image: delta-V savings]

The red dot represents the [Thaicom 6 satellite that SpaceX launched in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaicom_6) on a supersynchronous transfer orbit (90,000 km, [20.75°)](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/2988/40257). The $\Delta V$ savings was about 10%.

A higher transfer orbit of course takes more time to reach GEO:

[image: transfer time]

(normalized for the sake of electric propulsion satellites where the maneuvers can't all occur in one orbit)

Comment: Lets say the target orbit is GEO with zero inclination. Can you compare the GTO transfer orbit method launching from Cape Canaveral $28^{\circ}N$, 
vs the super synchronous orbit method launching from Cape Canaveral? Maybe same question from  the Baikonur Cosmodrome launching from $46^{\circ}N$?  For these two launch centers to GEO with zero inclination, how much lower is the $\Delta_v$ for the payload rocket's part of the $\Delta_v$?  Also, can the 2nd stage do any of the orbital inclination adjustment at Perigee?  To save additional fuel in the payload?

Comment: @Sheldon note that GEO is 0° inclination, and that every point of data in the charts shown is targeting GEO. Find the desired inclination (latitude) on the X axis and read the chart(s).

Comment: @Sheldon re: " 2nd stage do any of the orbital inclination adjustment at Perigee" I don't know, that is a much bigger analysis though.

Comment: I can eyeball the chart for $28^oN$ via GTO as $\Delta_V\approx$1.8, but having trouble with the corresponding number for super synchronous to 90km from $28^oN$. For the $46^oN$, case the GTO chart gives $\Delta_V\approx$2.25, again having trouble with the comparable super synchronous number.  I think a concrete example of the payload rocket's $\Delta_V$ savings would be helpful .... :)

Comment: Looks like the other inclination of interest for the Baikonur Cosmodrome launching from $46^oN$ is actually $51.6^oN$ because the Russian don't want space debris falling into China when a Russian rocket fails, so the Russians typically launch into a slightly higher orbital inclination, just to be safe.

The only other orbital inclination the *might be* interesting would be the Guiana Space Centre at $5^oN$.  *I can see no value whatsoever* to any of the numbers in the chart ....

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking I'm really sorry if I sound offensive.  I just felt like the answer provided ... wasn't really an answer, and I was trying to explain why the colored charts didn't seem helpful to me.  I *think* the chart says the savings from Cape Canaveral at $28^oN$ super synchronous to 90km  is *about* 8%, and *maybe about* 20% from the Baikonur Cosmodrome launching at $51.6^oN$ inclination.  But my guess is that I'm reading the charts wrong and maybe the savings is higher.  Then again, maybe that's all the super synchronous launch saves, I don't know.

Comment: @Sheldon don't worry about that person, I will update the charts a little later to make them easier to read :)

Comment: Sorry for spamming BrenanLuke, but one more request: I noticed the 2014 case is 90km was to 90,000 km, $20.7^oN$, but launched from $28^oN$!!   *What we want to compare* against for the final rocket engine firing $\Delta_V$ is actually the 90,000km super synchronous case launched from Cape Canaveral is actually the GTO launch to $28^oN$!!!    So that's another reason why two or three specific examples might be better than the chart.  Some of the savings for the payload's rocket is doing less inclination adjustment as well.  How much $\Delta_V$ can you save in the *payload's* rocket!!

Comment: @Sheldon does this help at all? I hesitate to include a concrete example (outside of the Thaicom-6 one) because the supersynchronous transfer is multivariate (hence the contour plots) and that is not what is requested in OP

Comment: This chart helps: "For the supersynchronous method, the ΔV cost..."  However, nobody launches to GEO with an inclination higher than $51.6^{o}N$, correct???  So I would crop *all* of the the inclination charts to 0...60 degrees, making them much more relevant.  Then at $28^{o}N$ the benefit of super synchronous seems quite small unless the 2nd stage helps with some of the apogee adjustment burns... and the benefit of launching from Guiana Space Centre at $5^{o}N$ using GTO is *always* the winner in getting to GEO most efficiently.